# Data points in R plot of condition "0" not visible

Tags: r, plot

I tried to draw a xy plot in R using spec_conditions as a color-code. Unfortunately, data points of spec_condition = 0 do not show or show only in transparent. This is my code so far:

```
plot(m.mx$V6, m.mx$m.pmtl83351, col=spec_conditions,
       pch=16,
       main = "pMTL 83351 + placORMi")
  axis(1, at=m.mx$V6, labels=m.mx$V6, cex.axis=1, cex.lab=0.1)
  legend("topleft",
         legend = spec_conditions,
         col=spec_conditions,
         cex=0.8,
         inset=0.01,
         pch = c(rep(16,7)))
```

[image: show plot example here]

Comment: Try adding 1 to spec_conditions

Comment: there is no `color 0` in R; R `colors()` has 657 colors in total, but starting from 1; if you want to specify colors explicitly, use color names

Comment: Thank you for your comments!
Maybe my question was not so clear, I want to use different colors for each condition, so I can distinguish my data points by color. For each condition I want to use a different color:
spec_conditions <- c(400, 200, 100, 50, 25, 12.5, 0)
The color palette is therefore not important

Comment: @emba passing colors by their index is not intended in R; the fact it works is a side effect; you either pass colors by names, use a palette, or use a completely different approach, such as in `ggplot2` package

Comment: Now I understand my problem! It is enough to put 
`legend = spec_conditions` and add a color palette to `col`
@everyone Thank you so much!